# Opening commands in new terminal with new profile

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm using OSX Yosemite and the built-in terminal on my Mac. I have quite a few terminal windows running most of the time and it's hard to navigate around in all of them as they all look alike. So what I want to do is run my commands as usual, but in a new terminal window with a chosen profile.

Normally to open my_script in vim I would type in command line

```
$ vim my_script
```

but I want to be able to write something like this:

`$ vim my_script` (as before) and then some command saying "open this in a new terminal window with profile = Homebrew"

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Enter AppleScript.

It doesn't achieve *exactly* what you describe but I think it's close enough. Whether or not you use this is up to you.

You can use this command

```
osascript -e 'tell app "system events" to tell process "Terminal" to tell menu bar 1 to tell menu bar item "Shell" to tell menu "Shell" to tell menu item "New Window" to tell menu "New Window" to click menu item "Basic"'
```

or, in expanded form

```
tell app "system events" 
    tell process "Terminal" 
        tell menu bar 1 
            tell menu bar item "Shell" 
                tell menu "Shell" 
                    tell menu item "New Window" 
                        tell menu "New Window" 
                            click menu item "Basic" #or any other profile
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

To create a new Terminal window with the desired profile. (In this example I used Basic)

If you get the error

```
System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed assistive access
```

then see [this SO answer by @NGAFD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31030767/2773311) on how to solve that.

Go to System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility and make sure Terminal is in the list and checked.